# Weird Symbols when connecting to windows througth SSH on java (Jsch)

Tags: java, windows, ssh, jsch, printstream

I am trying to execute a command in windows XP with Jsch Shell channel, but for some reason i get weird symbols in my System.out stream and the commands cannot be executed, the code that i use  for connect is this:

```
this.session = jsch.getSession(this.login, this.host);

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(this.password);
session.setConfig(properties);

session.connect(30000);


channel =(ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");


PipedInputStream pip = new PipedInputStream(40);
channel.setInputStream(pip);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

PipedOutputStream pop = new PipedOutputStream(pip);
print = new PrintStream(pop); 
channel.connect();
```

Then i get The following message:

```
[1;1HMicrosoft Windows XP [Versi�n 5.1.2600][2;1H(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.[4;1HC:\Documents and Settings\diego\Escritorio>[4;44H
```

And when i try to call a cd C:\MyFolder\ then another command (all tested from a ssh client and works) i gen more weird symbols and dont get the results of my commands, What can be the problem? Following is the commands that i send and the result:

```
exec.print.println("cd C:\\MyFolder\\");
exec.print.println("some other command");
```

result:

```
[1;1HMicrosoft Windows XP [Versi�n 5.1.2600][2;1H(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.[4;1HC:\Documents and Settings\diego\Escritorio>[4;44H[4;1HC:\Documents and Settings\diego\Escritorio>c[4;58H[4;1HC:\Documents and Settings\diego\Escritorio>cd C:\MyFolder\[4;58H[4;46H[4;58H[4;47H[4;58H[4;48H[4;58H[4;49H[4;58H[4;50H[4;58H[4;51H[4;58H[4;52H[4;58H[4;53H[4;58H[4;54H[4;58H[4;55H[4;58H[4;56H[4;58H[4;57H[4;58H
```

I am using a FreeSShd in windows xp and the program runs on Ubuntu, i use ssh in my console and works with the windows XP, i am trying to implement it in my java program, thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried direct ssh? If direct ssh works, then its jsch. Try jsch with a linux based ssh server. If jsch works then it is FreeSshd issue.

Comment: thanks,like i said in my question i try direct ssh but i dont say that i use ssh from ubuntu, that works, the same code that i try to use in windows i used it in my ubuntu and also works, but with windows dont, so only can be FreeSSHd, but i read that is the best free ssh for windows and the most easy to install, any ssh server suggestion? thanks.

Comment: @Usman Saleem your suggestion was right, i install openssh in my windows and all works fine, thanks :D

Comment: No issues Diego :), I will add my comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221127/funny-shell-output-0132mtestfile-txt00m-instead-of-testfile-txt

i found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried direct ssh? If direct ssh works, then its jsch. Try jsch with a linux based ssh server. If jsch works then it is FreeSshd issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding problem plus a lack of terminal emulation.

The SSH daemon expects to talk to a device that understands terminal control sequences (the `[1;1H` string, which is actually preceded by an `ESC` character).  Your program does not provide terminal emulation, so you see the raw escape sequences.

The diamond/question-mark character indicates that the font you are using doesn't contain the character sent by the server.  In this case it may be an accented character.

Comment: U+FFFD indicates that there was a conversion from Unicode to a legacy character set which lost information in the process *OR* there was an invalid code unit sequence (applicable to UTF-8 and UTF-16). It has nothing to do with fonts.

Comment: thanks, the windows is in spanish language so the diamond/question is really ó (versión), how i can set a font in this case for that?, and how i can use the correct terminal emulation? Jsch has a method like channel.setPty maybe is what i need?