# Funny Shell Output: [01;32mtestfile.txt[00m instead of testfile.txt

Tags: java, linux, ssh, terminal, jsch

**Question:** I'm getting "funny" character output from commands I send when using a [ChannelShell](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell.html) and I'm wondering how to get just the regular output you see in a PuTTY session.

By "funny" I mean I should see this:

```
testfile.txt
```

And I'm seeing this:

```
[01;32mtestfile.txt[00m
```

This is similar to the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641192/why-do-i-see-scrabbled-output-when-using-jsch) except the answer does not satisfy my need. The answer there is to call `setPty(false)` on the ChannelShell which removes the "pseudo-terminal" entirely, but I need to have the output from the ChannelShell in real time. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
ChannelShell channel = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setOutputStream(new PrintStream(
    new ByteArrayOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8") {
        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
            super.write(b, off, len);
            String output = new String(b, off, len);
            System.out.print(output);
            sendNextCommand(output); //Execution of the next command depends on the output here, this is why I need it to not have the funny characters.
        }
    });
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
channelInput = new PipedOutputStream(in);
channel.setInputStream(in);
channel.connect();

while(!channel.isClosed() && channelWaitRetries++ < MAX_CHANNEL_WAIT_RETRIES) {
    //Wait for additional output... Sort of a timeout deal. Kind of a hack...
    sleep(2500); //Calls Thread.sleep. I just don't want the try/catch here.
    System.out.println("Channel not yet closed. Retried " + channelWaitRetries + " of " + MAX_CHANNEL_WAIT_RETRIES);
}
```

The sendNextCommand method is where the check is done to see if the output matches the what needs to be showing for the next command to execute. So basically, when I see something like this: `[user@server ~]$` then execute this: `ls` which should return this: `testfile.txt` but **instead** it is returning this: `[01;32mtestfile.txt[00m` (NOTE: I can't copy and paste the first character, but it's a box with the char code of 27 which I think is an escape character).

Now I would normally just escape this kind of thing, but I'd rather get it done right, and it also seems like there are a number of variants to the weirdness. So here I am. I hope you can help :)

Note: I'm running this through my Windows machine through my IDE (an eclipse rip-off), but I've tried debugging and the variable `output` actually shows the "funny" characters. I've also tried showing it in a `JOptionPane.messageDialog` just to make sure it's not just the IDE and it still has the characters. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a solution:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830620/getting-strange-output-from-the-remote-shell-in-jsch

Have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are ANSI escape sequences, in the case of `ls`, to control the colour.

`ls` has a `--color=never` option which should resolve the specific `ls` problem.

Is this happening on all commands, or just some?

Calling `ChannelShell.setPtyType("dumb")` could also help (untested). You may need to fiddle around to find a terminal type that disables the escape sequences.

Any particular reason you are shelling `ls` rather than using built-in Java methods to check for  directory contents?

Comment: I'd say it's happening to most commands. I haven't tried a ton of commands, but I do run scripts which run multiple commands and the output of some of those commands contains some of these ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference with "dumb." I'm not sure if I know all of the terminal types. A quick search took me to my `/etc/termcap` file and it looks like there's a "vanilla" type that I thought would be promising, but to no avail. Am I missing something? Setting the `PtyType` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you calling setPtyType() before connect() ? 

It may be worth posting a link to a self-contained minimal example to reproduce the problem, rather than an incomplete extract as above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a TOTAL shot in the dark, but that looks like either a UNIX/Windows text encoding issue or perhaps there are some UNIX color codes that aren't getting parsed correctly.  I have seen that before - usually in older shells on Unix/Linux that didn't have color support or with Cygwin shells that were sshed into a UNIX machine that invoked an old c-shell terminal (we run some very old Solaris 8 machines - barf).

I'm not sure if that helps, but maybe gives you something to think about.